# Resize a 2:1 image to put into a 1:1 div

Tags: css, image-resizing

Just want to let all the product images using the same 1:1 responsive area. The problem is, if the image is 2:1, it uses more space than expected (1:1).
How to use css to resize it to show like this? (first example)

current setting:

```
max-width: 100%;
width: 100%;
height: auto;
max-height: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, kindly add your code snippet here so that anyone can fix your issue.

Comment: Do you want to stretch the image to fit? Or do you want to fit it inside the square?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `object-fit:cover;` to cover the entire container where the image is in.
In the following example, I've loaded in a 200x100 pixel image, and contained it in a 100x100 pixel area.

Note that IE does not support this: https://caniuse.com/#search=object-fit

```css
#product {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
}

#product img {
  object-fit:cover;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="product">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x100&text=productimage">
</div>
```